# How to install web2py on Centos 6 with ip public

Tags: web2py, centos6

Please explain me how to install web2py on my Centos 6 vps .of I try to run it with python2.7 web2py ,it just run on localhost .

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended that you use the included Rocket server for production, but you can do:

```
python web2py.py -a 'your password' -i 0.0.0.0 -p 80
```

Comment: Thank you... i will try it. But it will used production server.

Comment: To set up a different web server, you could use the [one step production deployment](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/13/deployment-recipes#One-step-production-deployment) instructions. There are a number of additional setup scripts [here](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/tree/master/scripts) for different servers and OSes.

Comment: Thank you Anthony. I 've read it and tried it yesterday but still error.  I don't know why https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/scripts/setup-web2py-fedora.sh that updated 16 days ago still use old application.
You may see python 2.6.4 and mod_wsgi 3.3 . I was install on my vps pyhon 2.7.5 and mod_wsgi 3.4